# Необходимо у строки(string) А упорядочить символы в порядке, обратном к алфавитному

Tags: c++, строки, сортировка

Само задание полностью выглядит так : "через одну пустую строку предлагает ввести строку A (ввод осуществляется нажатием клавиши Enter), а затем строку В. После этого необходимо вывести обработанные строки. Если строки состоят из одних и тех же символов, то удалить из B латинские и русские буквы; в остальных случаях упорядочить символы A в порядке, обратном к алфавитному"
P.S подключение других библиотек не рассматривается

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string a,b;
    cout << "Введите строку А : ";
    getline(cin,a);
    cout << "Введите строку B : ";
    getline(cin,b);

    cout << "А : " << a << endl;
    cout << "B : " << b << endl;

    if (a == b) 
    {
        for (int unsigned i = 0; i < b.size();i++) 
        {
            char ch = b[i];
            if ((((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) || ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))) || (((ch >= 'а') && (ch <= 'я')) || ((ch >= 'А') && (ch <= 'Я'))))
            {
                b.erase(i, 1);
                --i;
            }

        }
        cout << "B : " << b << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        /*Тут как раз не могу реализовать сортировку символов строки А в 
         обратном алфавитному порядке*/
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Если строки состоят из одних и тех же символов_ и `a == b` не совсем одно и то же. `b` должно быть перестановкой `a`, т.е. символы могут стоять на других позициях(`"1a*"` и `"a*1"` - состоят из одинаковых символов, но `a != b`). И не очень понятно, что делать с символами разных регистров. Должно быть CBAcba или cbaCBA или  CcBbAa или cCbBaA? Для первого варианта достаточно выполнить любую сортировку по убыванию над `a`.

Comment: Ошибся, не для первого, а для второго варианта